# Escaping in a sh script?

Tags: bash, sh

I've got the following line in my script:

```
xrandr --newmode "$xx$y" $m
```

where `$x` and `$y` are integers, to produce an output like `1024x768`.

Unfortunately my script is interpreting the `$x` as `$xx` - how can I stop this & get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to do it this way

```
"${x}x$y"
```

Have a look at [the docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_03) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The general logic is to isolate the variable so that it doesn't take `xx` as the variable name. There are several ways to do that:

Using quotes:

```
x="xvar";y="yvar"
echo ""$x"x$y"
echo ""$x"x"$y""
echo "$x""x""$y"
echo "$x"x"$y"
```

Using brace (mentioned by [Alberto Zaccagni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31379610/3744681)):

```
echo "${x}x$y"
```